# Hide hamburger menu on click outside the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have hamburger menu which works great, but I want to add some funtion, which will hide menu when user clicks OUTSIDE the whole hamburger menu.

```js
$(".cross").hide();
$(".mobilemenu").hide();
$(".hamburger").click(function() {
  $(".mobilemenu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
    $(".hamburger").hide();
    $(".cross").show();
  });
});

$(".cross").click(function() {
  $(".mobilemenu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
    $(".cross").hide();
    $(".hamburger").show();
  });
});

$(".clickham").click(function() {
  $(".mobilemenu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
    $(".cross").hide();
    $(".hamburger").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
  <button class="cross">&#735;</button>
</header>
<div class="mobilemenu">
  <ul>
    <a href="#" class="clickham">
      <li>Test</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="clickham">
      <li>Test2</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/71hdnctp/

Comment: $(document).click.....

Comment: I am added this: 
$(document).click(function() {
    $( ".mobilemenu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
 $( ".cross" ).hide();
 $( ".hamburger" ).show();
 });
});
$(".mobilemenu").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;       
});
$("header").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;       
});
But when hamburger menu is closed, then click anywhere opens menu.

Comment: Okay, I have good code:
$(document).click(function() {
    $( ".mobilemenu" ).hide(function() {
 $( ".cross" ).hide();
 $( ".hamburger" ).show();
 });
});
$(".mobilemenu").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;       
});
$("header").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;       
});
But how to have the slideToggle animation and combine this with function .hide?